# how to use apex_200100.www_flow_t_varchar2 as int or char

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

i have this sql query in an Apex application

```
select num_fac, id_fac
from fac
where id_fac in
(select result from (SELECT apex_string.split(id_facs,':') result
                     FROM proc
                     where id_contract=:p50_id_contract))
```

my problem is that the data types are not the same because whereas id_fac is an INT, result is a apex_200100.www_flow_t_varchar2 type, and every row is like this

```
apex_200100.www_flow_t_varchar2('122')
apex_200100.www_flow_t_varchar2('123')
apex_200100.www_flow_t_varchar2('145')
apex_200100.www_flow_t_varchar2('13')
```

i tried to use SUBSTR and INSTR but i get this message error

```
ora-00932 inconsistent datatypes expected char got apex_200100
```

any suggestions or solution?

Comment: Check this article https://www.talkapex.com/2020/03/optimizing-member-of-apex-string-split/

Comment: [`apex_string.split`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/SPLIT-Function-Signature-1.htm#AEAPI-GUID-3BE7FF37-E54F-4503-91B8-94F374E243E6) returns `apex_t_varchar2`, which is a table of varchar2 (according to its name). So the result of subquery is a set of rows where each row contains a table of varchar2. Of course you cannot compare such type with int.

Comment: @astentx and what is the solution here?

Comment: Let's all not forget that apex_string.split_numbers is a thing https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/aeapi/SPLIT_NUMBERS-Function.html#GUID-729E046F-4E95-45DF-8B9F-5FBEA0C08DE5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TABLE()` to convert the type return by apex_string to a pseudo-table.

```
SELECT column_value
FROM TABLE (SELECT apex_string.split('122:123:145:13',':') result
            FROM dual)
```

The full query should be something like this:

```
select num_fac, id_fac
from fac
where id_fac in
(SELECT TO_NUMBER(column_value)
  FROM TABLE (SELECT apex_string.split(id_facs,':') result
              FROM proc
              WHERE id_contract=:p50_id_contract));
```

If `id_contract` is not a unique key, then you can aggregate the lines into a single string using `LISTAGG` and the same separator `:`:

```
with fac as (
  select 'a' as num_fac, 1 as id_fac from dual
  union all select 'b' as num_fac, 1 as id_fac from dual
  union all select 'c' as num_fac, 1 as id_fac from dual
  union all select 'd' as num_fac, 2 as id_fac from dual
  union all select 'e' as num_fac, 2 as id_fac from dual
  union all select 'f' as num_fac, 3 as id_fac from dual
  union all select 'g' as num_fac, 4 as id_fac from dual
  union all select 'h' as num_fac, 5 as id_fac from dual),
proc as (
  select 100 as id_contract, '1:2' as id_facs from dual
  union all select 200 as id_contract, '3' as id_facs from dual
  union all select 200 as id_contract, '4:5' as id_facs from dual)
--
select num_fac, id_fac
from fac
where id_fac in
(SELECT TO_NUMBER(column_value)
  FROM TABLE (SELECT apex_string.split(LISTAGG(id_facs,':') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id_facs) ,':') result
              FROM proc
              WHERE id_contract=:p50_id_contract));
```

Comment: This was how i originally wrote the query but i got this error
```
ORA-01427: Single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

Comment: Do you have more than one row in `proc` for a single `id_contract`?

Comment: yes, apparently it returns an array  of apex_t_varchar2

Comment: I updated my answer to provide a solution when `id_contract` isn't unique in `proc`

Comment: that is exactly what i was looking for THANKS!!

Answer (score 2):

As long as the output of [`apex_string.split`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/SPLIT-Function-Signature-1.htm#AEAPI-GUID-3BE7FF37-E54F-4503-91B8-94F374E243E6) is a `apex_t_varchar2` (which looks like table of `varchar2`), you need to convert it into a result set to do `in` check. This may be done via lateral join which is available from version 12c and above.

```
/*Sample data*/
create table t as
select
  level as id,
  mod(level, 5) as val
from dual
connect by level < 20
;

/*Sample data for filter*/
create table t_filt as
select
  listagg(level, ':') within group(order by 1) as ids,
  mod(level, 4) as grp
from dual
connect by level < 15
group by mod(level, 8), mod(level, 4)
;
```

```
/*Perform filtering*/
select *
from t
where id in (
  select flt_exploded.id
  from t_filt flt_base
    /*Expand list for each row*/
    cross join lateral (
        select to_number(column_value) as id
        from table(apex_string.split(flt_base.ids, ':'))
    ) flt_exploded
  where flt_base.grp = 2
)
;


ID VAL 
-- --- 
 2   2 
10   0 
 6   1 
14   4
```

Or alternatively perform set membership check [`member of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Multiset-Conditions.html#GUID-228D6708-37E1-4C54-8715-7EC2CF5B5998):

```
/*Perform filtering*/
select *
from t
where exists (
  select 1
  from t_filt flt_base
  where flt_base.grp = 2
    and to_char(t.id, 'TM9') member of apex_string.split(flt_base.ids, ':')
)
;

ID VAL 
-- --- 
 2   2 
 6   1 
10   0 
14   4
```

Unfortunately I cannot find appropriate fiddle with APEX functions, so I've tested this in Oracle's free cloud.